# Change syntax for protractor step definitions from promises to async syntax

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, protractor, cucumber

I have a protractor-cucumber framework whose step definitions are somewhat structured as per this: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/support_files/step_definitions.md

I use a `return` and chain the promises together. Recently, I came across a different syntax called the `async` function. But, when I try to convert my step definitions to async, all the help files in the framework where I use say `module.exports` and `require()` display the following warning:

> [ts] File is a CommonJS module; it may be converted to an ES6 module.

When I run test cases since I can't access these helper files due to the error my tests cases fail. Like, my page object files, I am not able to access them from my tests. I think they don't get exported like they used to.

Could someone please advice me as to how I can change my test cases to async syntax without breaking them? How do I resolve the above issue without disrupting my tests in a major way.

**Adding code**
Here is a step from my step definition before the change
let { Given, Then, When } = require('cucumber');

```
Given(/^I am on the  "([^"]*)" page$/, function (home) {
    home = this.url.FDI_HOME;
    return browser.get(home);
});
```

Here is a step definition, after I change it to an async function

```
let { Given, Then, When } = require('cucumber');
Given(/^I am on the "([^"]*)" page$/, async function (home) {
    home = this.url.HOME
    await browser.get(home);
});
```

And I will change my other steps in similar fashion. Problem arises when I try to run the above step it fails saying that it is not able to access this.url.HOME. I have another file to supply URLs called the urls.js looks something like this

```
let targetStore = browser.params.store || 'bestbuy';
let FDI_HOST = browser.params.fdi;

module.exports = {
    HOME Page: 'https://homepage.com',
    Shop_Page: 'https://shop.com',
    storeLink: `http://www.${targetStore}.com`,
 };
```

I see three dots under the word "module.exports" in VS code and when I hover over it, it displays an error saying: [ts] File is a CommonJS module; it may be converted to an ES6 module.

I have tried to find a resolution to this but not been able to successfully make it. if I use the syntax as "async()=>{}" the test cases fails but when I use "async function(){}" then a few of the steps pass but not the other.

Comment: `advice me as to how I can change my test cases to async syntax without breaking them` you want advice on how to change code ... but you haven't shown a single line of code ... interesting

Comment: @JaromandaX I have added code. Please let me know if you'd like more examples

Comment: @fuzz: I did not down vote your answer. I do not have enough reputation to down vote / up vote an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> These are suggestions/hints. They visually indicate that vscode can perform an action to possibly refactor/improve your code, but they are not treated as errors.

You can disable them by adding `"javascript.suggestionActions.enabled": false` to your user/workspace settings.

[image]

[image]

Source: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/47299

Comment: Thanks for this info. But, even if I disable it, I am not able to access files that were written in javascript ES5. All the module.exports and requires() are showing me errors

Comment: @Monnie_tester what are your `tsconfig.json` `compilerOptions { ... }`? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Comment: Hi, i don't really have a tsconfig.json in my project. It is a javascript project. I set up protrcator-cucumber with javascript